# Is there open source model of multi-agent system of consumer behavior?

Tags: reference-request, agent-based-computing

I am trying to build models of consumer behavior (especially investigating the impact of advertising on purchase decisions) using multi agent systems but I wonder are there already available some open source models? I checked available models in the model libraries of the most popular MAS simulation tools (NetLogo, Repast and MASON) and found only one model and even that was connected with the spatial behaior specifically.

I have also checked the literature about MAS and consume behavior (surprisingly, it is not extensive!) and while there are description of simulation I did not managed to find published models, they all are closed.

So - are there open source MAS consumer behavior models available? Google gives none, but maybe there are some models in the deep web which is unavailable to Google?

Comment: What do you mean by "model", exactly? I find it hard to believe that there is a body of literature that does not contain the used models.

Comment: Literature describes lot of models, but there ar two drawbacks: 1) usually the description is not detailed enought, e.g. there is no statecharts, fromulae, list of variables and parameters; 2) always (up to my knowledge) there is no published implementation of models (e.g. as NetLogo model-program). I hope that maybe there exists some open source implementation of model. I would not like to start my model-program from scratch.

Comment: Try contacting the authors or your favorite model; chances are they'll be happy to share.

Comment: Maybe try the applied economics department?